# Tag merge request: [skyrim-special-edition], [skyrim-anniversary-edition] → [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim]

Tags: support, status-completed, tags, tag-rename-request, tag-synonyms

July 2022 update: Since the tags have now been synonymized by community voting, this post now serves as a tag **merge** request to the mods. [(Only moderators can perform a merge.)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) This is because many questions that have the [skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition) and [skyrim-anniversary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-anniversary-edition) tags still *don't* have the [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim) tag. Only merging will allow this to be done en-masse.

---

The original synonymize and merge request is as follows:

Currently, we have *three* (!) separate tags for *The Elder Scrolls V: Skyrim*, one for the original edition ([the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim)), one for the Special Edition ([skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition)) and one for the Anniversary Edition ([skyrim-anniversary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-anniversary-edition)). I was initially planning on making this a [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) post to ask how should we tag the different editions, but have found out that this has already been discussed back in 2016: ['Skyrim Special Edition' question handling](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/skyrim-special-edition-question-handling).

The community consensus in that meta post is to use one tag for all game editions. In line with that, I am requesting that [skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition) and [skyrim-anniversary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-anniversary-edition) be merged and synonymized to [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim).

I've looked at all the questions currently tagged [skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition) and [skyrim-anniversary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-anniversary-edition). The questions either already mention that they are about their specific editions, or are about an issue that is also in the original edition*. It should now be fine to merge the tags (as no edition information will be lost).

From the [tag info](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/synonyms) article:

> Users with more than 2500 reputation and a total answer score of 5 or more on the tag, can suggest tag synonyms. Users with a total answer score (total upvotes minus total downvotes) of 5 or more on the tag, can vote for tag synonyms. Suggestions will be automatically approved when they reach a score of 4 [...].

I've already suggested tag synonyms for the tags I've mentioned above. If you meet the requirements to vote for tag synonyms to [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim), please do so at: https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/synonyms.

Note that [only moderators can perform a merge.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/70710/what-are-tag-synonyms-and-merged-tags-how-do-they-work) Non-moderators can only do tag synonym suggestions and voting.

---

<sup>***** Relevant meta post: [Questions where OP has mentioned he/she is using a specific platform: how to answer, how to tag and when to close as exact duplicate?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5488/questions-where-op-has-mentioned-he-she-is-using-a-specific-platform-how-to-ans)</sup>

Comment: Skyrim Special Edition has some differences from the original edition. Notably, Special edition allows the use of mods and Skyrim Workshop content on console. If the questions aren't related to these features then they could likely be merged, but some questions have distinct properties that require tagging the correct version of Skyrim being played

Comment: @PausePause Yes there are differences, but the consensus at the [previous meta post](/q/12065) is that the differences are too minor that they don't justify having two separate tags. This is also consistent with how questions about "Special Editions" for other games are handled. The edition can be mentioned in the question body anyway so no need for a separate tag just to include that information. Also, we don't have separate tags for PC Skyrim, and Skyrim for the different consoles even if they have significant differences on mods that can be used and on usage of console commands.

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['Skyrim Special Edition' question handling](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12065/skyrim-special-edition-question-handling)

Comment: @Joachim I think this question should not be closed as a duplicate. This one is a request to the mods to merge and synonymize the tags. While the other is a discussion among the community on how to handle the tagging.

Comment: @galacticninja But shouldn't the merging and synonymizing of tags be based on the community's stance? We don't need threads for merging tags that simply need to be merged, especially if there is an ongoing discussion about it.

Comment: @Joachim The other question doesn't mention merging or synonymizing tags at all. This one is specifically a request (to the mods) to do just that.

Comment: @galacticninja True, but the reasoning behind it is there. And I felt that this merging, which is mostly a moderator task, could just take place without a "second" poll, since that thread shows the majority seems to agree with such an action. But I understand your point as well. In any case: I agree with the merging :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe this should all be done now, if you would like to verify, please do!

---

## Recap:

#### [Tag Synonyms](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tags/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim/synonyms) for [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim):

- [elder-scrolls-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/elder-scrolls-skyrim)
- [skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim)
- [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim)
- [skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition)
- [skyrim-anniversary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-anniversary-edition)

#### Tags merged into [the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim):

| Tag | Merge Date |
| --- | --- |
| [skyrim-anniversary-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-anniversary-edition) | July 25, 2022 |
| [skyrim-special-edition](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/skyrim-special-edition) | July 25, 2022 |
| [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim) | November 21, 2020 |

There is one tag left with 6 questions called [the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-elder-scrolls-5-skyrim-vr). I think we can *probably* leave this one though.